# How to apply a function to pairs of rows in a data.frame, similar to diff?

Tags: r

I've got a data frame that represents points in a plane.

```
     x     y
1  0.0   0.0
2  0.2   0.0
3  0.3  -0.1
...
```

I want to write a `diff`-like function for that data. I've written the distance function `myDist` (not Euclidean), but how can I apply it to the data frame?

That is: By calling `someFunction( myData, myDist )`, I want to obtain a vector with the values `myDist(myData[1,],myData[2,])`, `myDist(myData[2,],myData[3,])`, `myDist(myData[3,],myData[4,])`, ...

Is there a function that does this, or do I have to write a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with `lapply`:

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(myData) - 1),
    function(i){
        myDist( myData[i,], myData[i+1,] )
    })
```

Comment: I think you mean `1:(nrow(myData)-1)` or more safely (and quickly) `seq_len(nrow(myData) - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `head(myData, -1)` and `tail(myData, -1)` to get 2 datasets with the rows lined up the way you want, then if `myDist` is vectorized you would just pass the results to `myDist`, if it is not vectorized you could use `mapply` (or the `Vectorize` function), or `sapply`, `lapply`, `apply`, loops or other functionality.

```
myData <- data.frame( x=1:10, y=sample(1:10), z=rnorm(10) )

myDist <- function( one, two ) {
    sqrt( rowSums( (one-two)^2 ) )
}

myDist( head(myData,-1), tail(myData,-1) )
```