# R group pairs of rows in a dataframe based on true/false function

Tags: r

I need to create groups of rows from my dataframe using a custom function as grouping criteria. That function would compare two pairs of rows and returns true/false if those rows should be grouped together.

In an example dataset like:

```
id   field        code1  code2
1    textField1   055    066
2    textField2   100    120
3    textField3   300    350
4    textField4   800    450
5    textField5   460    900
6    textField6   490    700

                         ...
```

The function checks certain rules between the row fields by pair (*function(row1,row2)*) and returns *TRUE / FALSE* if those rows should be together.

I need to apply that function to all posible pairs in the dataframe and generate a list (or other structure) with all ID that matched to be together.

One way to apply the function to each pair is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505126/how-to-apply-a-function-to-pairs-of-rows-in-a-data-frame-similar-to-diff) :

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df) - 1),
       function(i){
         customFunction( df[i,], df[i+1,] )
       })
```

But I cannot think a way to group the rows that got *TRUE* as result

EDIT: Re-reading my question, seems in the need of an example:

If we created a matrix with all the posible combinations, the result would be:

```
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,]  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
[2,]  FALSE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
[3,]  FALSE  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
[4,]  FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
[5,]  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   TRUE
[6,]  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   TRUE
```

The resulting groups would be then:

```
1
2,3,4
5,6
```

Comment: It's not clear if you just want to aggregate all `TRUE`s together and all `FALSE`s together or you just want to aggregate consecutive `TRUE`s and `FALSE`. For example, if you get `T, T, T, F, F, T,T` so the output would be `1,2,3` then `4,5` and then `6,7`? OR you just `1,2,3,6,7` vs `4,5`? Or maybe some third option?

Comment: Changed the example with another one. Does this one explains a bit better what I try to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that does what you've specified:

```
mx <- matrix(c( TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,
FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,
FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,
FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,
FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,
FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),6)


groupings <- function(mx){

    out <- list()
    while(dim(mx)[1]){
        # get the groups that match the first column
        g = which(mx[,1])

        # expand the selection to any columns for which 
        # there is match in the first row
        (expansion = which(apply(cbind(mx[,g]),1,any)))
        while(length(expansion) > length(g)){
            g = expansion

            # expand the selection to any columns for which 
            # there is match to the current group
            expansion = which(apply(cbind(mx[,g]),1,any))
        }

        out <- c(out,list(g))
        mx <- mx[-g,-g]
    }
    return(out)

}

groupings(mx)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 2
```

Comment: How would you create the matrix from the initial dataset in an efficient way?

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653691/double-for-loop-to-calculate-averages-and-store-them-in-matrix/28653854) discusses a similar problem (with the answer restricted to the upper triangle), and is quite thorough.